# Implement PhpSpreadsheet in Codeigniter 4

Tags: phpspreadsheet, codeigniter-4

i am really a beginner and i am trying to install PhpSpreadsheet in Codeigniter 4 in the ThirdParty folder.
The instructions I find going around the net refer to "composer" but I have no idea how to run this command (I'm in Windows 10, XAMPP, Codeigniter 4.1.1 and PHP 7.3).
I would still like to install everything manually.

So I proceeded like this:

- In the ThirdParty folder I created a PhpOffice folder and downloaded the contents of PhpSpreadsheet.
- I then modified the Autoload.php file (from the codeigniter app/Config folder) in this way:

public $psr4 = [

```
APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace

'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',

'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet' => APPPATH . 'ThirdParty/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet',
```

];

Then I created the Example.php controller like so:

```
<? php
namespace App\Controllers;

use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

class Example extends BaseController
{
    public function index ()
    {
        $ spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet ();
    }
}
```

Well this line of code alone generates the following error:

Error

Interface 'Psr \ SimpleCache \ CacheInterface' not found

APPPATH \ ThirdParty \ PhpOffice \ PhpSpreadsheet \ Collection \ Memory.php at line 13

I have no idea how to fix.
Thanks in advance to all those who will answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php office and any other libraries have some dependencies (libraries that are needed in the main library).So we usually use package managers like Composer (in PHP) for handling stuff like that.
In this case, Phpoffice tells you Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface is a required package for running some scripts.

Installing/using Composer package is very easy on all platforms.
After installing you just need to include "vendor/autoload.php" file in your code and use every installed package.

Also use **$config['composer_autoload'] = APPATH . 'vendor/';** for setting your composer vendor directory for autoloading by codeigniter itself.

For adding phpoffice/phpspreadsheet you just need to run command below and all dependencies will install automatically for you.

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

(vendor is the directory that composer packages will install on it.)

Comment: kind for the answer but this opens me up to several other questions about how to install and get the library up and running in Codeigniter 4. I am a beginner. Can you go into more detail? I downloaded Composer. (I also hope I can do that on a shared hosting)

Comment: What kind of detail do you need ? After installing it on your machine you can get packages and even if your shared hosting does not access you a shell for installing composer you can move vendor directory with your FTP access or any other solution you have like git and so on. so don't worry about that.

Comment: thanks again for the reply. I'm really a beginner, try to understand me. I just got to run the "composer require phpoffice / phpspreadsheet" command. I now have a Vendor folder in my Codeigniter ThirdParty folder. I tried to change the controller with the following two lines of code to point to the class folder:

use ThirdParty \ vendor \ phpoffice \ phpspreadsheet \ src \ PhpSpreadsheet;
use ThirdParty \ vendor \ phpoffice \ phpspreadsheet \ src \ PhpSpreadsheet \ Writer \ Xlsx;

But I can't figure it out

Comment: You should not include vendor packages directly. You just need to include **vendor/autoload.php** in your script.

Comment: could you rewrite my controller?

Comment: Do you add PathTo/vendor/autoload.php in your Codeigniter config file?
In your case I think it's $config['composer_autoload'] = APPATH . 'ThirdParty/vendor/';

Comment: It's Codeigniter 4

Comment: I have no idea if CI4 has been changed in this. You can require_once the autoload.php by your self for example in index.php file (if it's still there in CI4) or in any other places even in your controller file. But after  getting hello world you should use a best practice model for adding that.

Comment: has anyone else installed phpspreadsheet with Codeigniter 4 already? I have no idea which file to edit and how to edit it. I'm not very knowledgeable about classes. Who has a sample controller?
I have already entered the line:

require_once APPPATH.'ThirdParty / vendor / autoload.php ';

but I get the error

App \ Controllers \ Spreadsheet 'not found

Comment: If it was useful for you, please mark it as accepted. thx

Answer (score 1):

Well, I launched the phpSpreadsheet download with composer from the Codeigniter 4 application root and then created the following controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;


class Example extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working now!
No need to edit other files.
Thanks again to those who answered me, the information was useful