# How to use library in CI4?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a website with PHP 7.4.15 and CI 4.1.1.
I need to use phpspreadsheet library so I installed it by composer.

but when I try to use that class , the below error shows.

`Class 'PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Spreadsheet'` not found

According to CI4 documents, CI4 find Composer Auto Load files.
Do I need to set other things?

Any ideas can be helpful for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement PhpSpreadsheet in Codeigniter 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66334823/implement-phpspreadsheet-in-codeigniter-4)